# how to play/display video in a directory with html5

Tags: php, html, mysql

I do not know how to get videos in a folder to play in html or php. I know how to do a single video but that's not what I want. I want to display and play videos that are in a directory folder. Is their a certain way to do this. I tried this code but it doesn't work and I tried other codes. I know in the code below its connected to a database. I have managed to upload videos but can't display them.

none of the solutions given is working but let me ask a simpliar question can I do this to get not just one particular video but all the videos with a path to the folder with videos. I think the code above has a lot of errors and it was the only one i could find so I'm not trusting the code above.

Comment: you confirmed that the videos in the correct folder? try: `while($fetch1=mysql_fetch_array($select)) { print_r($fetch1);` and tell me what appears

Comment: [You should not be using `mysql_query`](http://php.net/mysql_query), your query is prone to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), your PHP [pretty printing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_style) is non-existent, your HTML `source` syntax is inconsistent, and you have not [escaped](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) the `$video` value for the [URI-reference](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986).  But other than that I can see nothing inherently wrong here.

Comment: Look at your html source code, in the browser after the php has parsed. Are your source `src` paths correct?

Comment: I'm not sure how you know that the query is prone to SQL injection @PointedEars. If he fully controls `$id`, or if he has properly escaped it, there is nothing wrong with that line. OP is doing a lot of things wrong, but I feel like you're just fishing there to add one more thing.

Comment: @Conexion With this code, it is not far-fetched.

Comment: OP: You cannot insert multiple videos this way. Please do research before you post, all documentation of the used technologies is freely available.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following?

```
 <?php
    $query = "select * from videos where `id`='" . $id . "'";
    $select = mysql_query($query);

    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select)) != null)
    {
        $video = $row['video'];

        print '<video width="320" height="240" controls>' .
                '<source src="uploadvideo/' . $video . '" type="video/mp4">' . 
                '<source src="video/' . $video . '" type="video/ogg" />' .
                'Your browser does not support the video tag.' .
            '</video>';
    }
?>
```

There are a few tweaks in there, such as using backticks around the column name, inputting a message for if your browser does not support the video tag ([taken from here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)), and handling a null result.

Also, maybe you need to stick a `/` in front of `video/` and `uploadvideo/`? e.g. if your videos are located in one folder below the document root, such as wwww.mydomain.com/video/vid-name-here.mp4

Another thing, have you removed the file extensions from all the videos, or is the file extension kept in the database for both mp4 and ogg videos? Perhaps you want to attach .mp4 and .ogg accordingly in the source links to be like so:

```
'<source src="uploadvideo/' . $video . '.mp4" type="video/mp4">' . 
'<source src="video/' . $video . '.ogg" type="video/ogg" />' .
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
    $query = "select * from `videos` where `id`='" . $id . "'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
        $video = $row['video'];

        echo '<video width="320" height="240" controls>' .
                '<source src="uploadvideo/' . $video . '" type="video/mp4">' . 
                '<source src="video/' . $video . '" type="video/ogg" />' .
                'Your browser does not support the HTML5 tags.' .
            '</video>';
     }
   }
?>
```